# Convert expression to C-form and simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression which is the sum of many terms of the form

$$
\frac{0.00000000274341}{(0.000363856+(0.611425+z)^2)^{3/2}}
$$

My problem is that I need to include this long expression in a C++-program I made, so all the exponents $^2$ and $^{3/2}$ I need to bring on a C++-compatible form. If I use `CForm`, then the exponents become `pow(..., 2)` and `pow(..., 1.5)`, respectively.

In order to speed up my program, I would like for all the `pow(..., 2)` expression to be converted to `(...)*(...)` and for the `pow(..., 1.5)` to be converted to `(...)*pow(..., 0.5)`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: seems like string replacement can work for you? and why do you think x*pow(x, 0.5) is faster than pow(x, 1.5)?

Comment: @asterix314 I found an optimized `sqrt`-function in C++, so I would like to write it all in terms of that.. I'll dig up the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an summation

```
expr = Sum[RandomReal[]/(RandomReal[] + (RandomReal[] + z)^2)^(3/2), {2}]
```

[image: summation]

Will the following work for you?

```
expr //. {x_^2 :> HoldForm[x*x], x_^(-3/2) :> 1/(x* sqrt[x]) } // CForm
```

[image: converted to C form]